# C++ CRTP Name Lookup

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

Why does this code fail to compile (undeclared identifier 'x', both g++ 4.9 and clang++ 3.5)?

```
template <class T>
struct base {
    int x;
};

template <class U>
struct end : public base<U> {
    end() {
        x = 5;
    }
};
```

Note:  Explicitly specifying `this->x` solves the problem.

Comment: I see the problem using g++ 4.8.2 using still simpler code: `template <class T>
struct base 
{
   int x;
};

template <class U>
struct end : public base<U> {
   end() {
      x = 10;
   }
};
`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not compile because dependant base classes are ignored during name lookup, and `base` is a dependant base.

You can use the `this` pointer :

```
end() {
    this->x = 5;
}
```

Or just explicitly name the base class :

```
end() {
    base::x = 5;
}
```

**Note:**

- See the relevant entry in the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/nondependent-name-lookup-members.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since sometimes you may want to use `>>` as binary operator (right shift), this does not compile in gcc and clang (it compiles with MSVC 13).

Easy fix is adding a space from `>>` to `> >`:

```
 class end : public middle<end<U> >
```

This works:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class base {
public:
    int x;
};

template <class T>
class middle : public base {};

template <class U>
class end : public middle<end<U> > {
    public:
        end() {
        base::x = 5;
    }
};

int main()
{
    end<middle<base> > e;
    cout << e.x << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Didn't even realize that - I've aliased my compilers to include C++11 by default.  That's not the issue, though - The error I get is about an undefined identifier.

Comment: Ok.. However, it is valid and compiles in MSVC 13 in case you mind.

Comment: @Robert Mason: Ouch.. Too late!

Comment: Always seems to be a race here on stack overflow... thanks for taking a look!

Comment: in c++11 >> is correctly distiguished when is a template closing brace.

Comment: @DarioOO: how do you know that the code in the question is c++11?